# Accessing cmdline arguments on 32-bit assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, masm

So I'm currently trying to get the command line arguments using masm, here is what I've done so far:

```
.386
.MODEL FLAT

includelib kernel32.lib
includelib msvcrt.lib

__getmainargs PROTO C :DWORD
printf        PROTO C :DWORD

.data
            str_argv     db "argv[1]: %s",0
.fardata?
            argc    dd ?    
            argv    db 255 DUP(?)
            env     dd  ?

.code
START:
            push 0
            push OFFSET env
            push OFFSET argv
            push OFFSET argc
            call  __getmainargs
            add   esp, 4*4 ;4 args
 
            push  [edi]
            push  OFFSET str_argv
            call  printf
            add   esp, 4 * 2 ;2 args

            ret
END START
```

However this returns me a garbage string that does not correspond to the cmdline argument, in this case the module name.

Any ideas why this doesn't work? -> Also are there any other alternatives for accessing cmdline args?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pushing `[edi]` without having put the correct value into `edi`.

Change the declaration of `argv` to `argv dd ?`.

Then change the `push [edi]` to:

```
mov edi,argv
push dword ptr [edi+4]
```

And make sure you use the `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` option when linking.